# How to find how much space is wasted in a table from Direct Path /*+ APPEND */ Inserts?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

A direct path insert into a table will have Oracle create new blocks above the high water mark, whereas a conventional insert would fill up any unused/freed blocks below the high water mark. This is why it is suggested to only use a direct path insert for large amounts of data, as repeated direct path inserts will waste a lot of space.

I have a table where no deletes, updates, or conventional inserts have only been performed - the only action that has been taken is direct path inserts.

How can I find out how much space in each of blocks below the high water mark have been wasted due to abuse of direct path inserts?

Answer (score 0):

You could get a quick approximation with some simple assumptions:

```
SQL> select blocks, empty_blocks, round(avg_row_len * num_rows / ( 1 - pct_free/100) * ( 8192 / ( 8192 - 100 ) )/8192 ) guess_blks
  2  from user_tables
  3  where table_name = 'T';

    BLOCKS EMPTY_BLOCKS GUESS_BLKS
---------- ------------ ----------
      1563            0       1430
```

So in my case, my table consumes 1563 blocks and using a rough algorithm of row length * number of rows, adjusted for pctfree and adjusted for 100bytes of overhead per block, my guess at how many blocks I need is around 1430.  I could then also compare that to actual space consumed by looking at user_segments

```
SQL> select bytes/8192 from user_Segments
  2  where segment_name = 'T';

BYTES/8192
----------
      1664
```

Answer (score -1):

first you need know the pctfree of one table in oracle.

then the dbms_space package will help you.

from your description of question and your repuation/badge,

i think details will be quickly gained by your research.

Comment: This could be a good answer if it had a full example.  Yes, the OP could research it himself based on the information you provided, but why make him spend the extra effort?

Comment: @Jon Heller , as i only know pctfree/dbms_space will help him. and also i need research for details such as how to use the specified method/function.